# How to display salesforce data on a Google Map?

Tags: visualforce, google-map

I am a beginner user here, but I've been tasked with developing maps of our volunteers.  There are two types of volunteers (contacts), CDL Drivers and Plain Volunteers.  I have researched a few pages and it is suggested that APEX code be used.  But, I have no idea what I'm doing here.  Any suggestions where to start?

Thank you

Comment: There's a new feature called `Maps & Location Services` that has been released. https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_maps.htm&siteLang=en_US I have personally not tried this yet but you can check if this help your cause.

Comment: The upcoming spring release also contains a visualforce component for google maps! If no one beats me to it i'll try to write up an answer after work. (I've taken the liberty to modify your title slightly so that your question becomes easier to find for others).

Answer (score -1):

Here are high level steps how you can do it:
•   Create Bew VF page
•   Write your code to show google map
•   Insert that page on any layout or call it directly by passing ID

Here is link that gives step by step description on what to do
http://www.minddigital.com/how-to-integrate-google-maps-into-your-salesforce-software/

Try this as it is then create another copy for contact object and do required changes.